# Array of int serialization java

Tags: java, sockets

I have an array of int which I want to send to other server using socket programming but it does not work correct I am wondering to know that should I serilized my array or not?

```
 public Integer[] array=new Integer[5]; 
 //I give some dummy value to array then I send. I have no error and the other side
 // receive it but with wrong value      
 in=new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
 out=new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
 out.writeObject(new packet(array));  

  import java.io.Serializable;
  public class packet implements Serializable
   {
     public Integer[] vec=null;
     public packet(Integer[] vector){
     vec=vector;}
   }
  //On the other side I have in=new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    private packet getPacket() throws IOException
    {
        packet p;
    try {
            p=(packet) in.readObject();
            if (p != null)              
                return p;
        } 
    }

   `
```

Comment: We would need to know what a "packet" is, what the receive code on the other end looks like, and what wrong values you're seeing on the other end before we could help you at all.

Comment: You didn't say what values you're seeing on the other end, or how you know it's not working right.

Comment: for example I send [1 0] at other side I see[0 0]!!

Comment: Everything here is OK. The devil is in the details, though. It's clear that this isn't the real code, but rather your summary of the code, and so you've accidentally fixed *something* while summarizing it. The most likely problem you're having is that Java serialization will, by default, only write a given object to a stream once; so if you write an array, change the contents, and write it again, the second instance will come over the wire as just a reference to the first, with the first set of values. Cloning the array in your "packet" constructor, as someone else has mentioned, would help!

Comment: Wow many thanks It works now. Sorry I can't give + point to your answer(it is disabled!)

Comment: I will repost as an answer...

Comment: That is exactly what I referred to when I said 'provided you understand what `ObjectOutputStream.reset()/writeUnshared()` are for'.

Comment: If writing the constructor the way I proposed fixed it, I think my answer ought to be voted up and accepted.  Give credit where it's due.

Comment: Sorry I can not vote up it is disable for me:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything here is OK. The devil is in the details, though. It's clear that this isn't the real code, but rather your summary of the code, and so you've accidentally fixed something while summarizing it. The most likely problem you're having is that Java serialization will, by default, only write a given object to a stream once; so if you write an array, change the contents, and write it again, the second instance will come over the wire as just a reference to the first, with the first set of values. Cloning the array in your "packet" constructor, as someone else has mentioned, would definitely help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good idea:

```
public class packet implements Serializable {

    public Integer[] vec=null;

    public packet(Integer[] vector) {
       vec=vector;
    }
}
```

A public, mutable member variable?  And assigning that way makes it possible for anyone to change the state of packet.

Here's how I would re-write the bit that you posted:

```
public class Packet implements Serializable {

    private Integer [] vector;

    public Packet(Integer [] vector) {
       this.vector = new Integer[vector.length];
       System.arraycopy(0, vector, 0, this.vector, vector.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you think it is ok not to serialized the array of int?

Comment: @sweet: Maybe it's me, but I don't see him saying anything of the kind.

Comment: This is a (rare) case for cloning actually, rather than `System.arrayCopy()`.

Comment: I created a new array and copied the source into it.  Same result as cloning.

Comment: I'm saying that you didn't construct the object correctly.  I said nothing about your serialization problem.  I just wanted to fix the incorrect snippet that I saw.

Comment: @duffymo of course it's the same result, that's why I suggested it.

Answer (score 1):

You will save about 90% of serialization space requirements if you make the array `int[]` instead of `Integer[]`. Other than that there is no reason why your code won't work correctly provided you understand what `ObjectOutputStream.reset()/writeUnshared()` are for.

Also, testing the result of `readObject()` for `null` is pointless unless you are planning to send nulls. It doesn't return null at EOS as a lot of people seem to conclude at first: it throws an EOFException.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the question, it helped me very much. I just want to add some things I've just learned for completeness.

- EJP's answer was not that helpful. He wanted to consider using `writeUnshared`. Given the `packet` implementation of the question his method won't help you with the problem because

  > the rules described above only apply to the base-level object written with writeUnshared, and not to any transitively referenced sub-objects in the object graph to be serialized

  Source: [`ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared%28java.lang.Object%29)
  In other words, the "sub object" of the int array won't be affected from `writeUnshared`.
- I have seen several requests for multidimensional arrays on StackOverflow. I think it's worthy to mention that a plain call to `arraycopy` on the first dimension won't accomplish the job. You have to copy every array that does not contain arrays itself manually. Given the packet as above with a two dimensional array of integers, it would look something like this (constructor with `int[][]` parameter must be added):

  ```
  public packet copy() {
      // lets assume it's a square matrix
      int[][] temp = new BoardItem[vec.length][vec.length];
      for(int i = 0; i < vec.length; i++) {
          System.arraycopy(vec[i], 0, temp[i], 0, vec.length);
      }
      return new packet(temp);
  }
  ```

  After this modification the basic programm would be

  1. creating a `packet`
  2. sending object
  3. altering `vec`
  4. sending a new packet object by calling recently added `copy` method
  5. repeat beginning with 3 if not done

I personally use these steps for repeatedly altering the board of a network game and sending correct data to clients.