# Using 2 pipes to transfer between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, pipe

I have to create a program which uses threads and pipes in Java.
I have to create 2 classes which are threads. The 1st class makes a random number, then it has to pass to the 2nd class (it will have to be increased once) and then it will have to go back to the 1st class which will be printed out. To transfer this integer I have to use 2 pipes to transfer this integer.

In shortcut:

> ```
> Class 1:
> Creates a random number.
> Sends it to the class 2.
>
> Class 2:
> Increase the number by 1.
> Send it back to the class 1.
>
> Class 1:
> Prints the result.
> ```

How to create something like that?
Thanks for help!

I have to use classes PipedOutputStream and PipedInputStream to solve my problem. I can't use anything else.

Comment: check out BlockingQueues.  btw, "pipe" is a bad term for what you want because it implies "streaming".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [`java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)? You could have some setup like this:

```
class WriteThread extends Thread {

    private BlockingQueue<Integer> createdIntegers;
    private BlockingQueue<Integer> processedIntegers;

    public WriteThread(BlockingQueue<? extends Integer> createdIntegers, BlockingQueue<? extends Integer> processedIntegers){
        this.createdIntegers = createdIntegers;
        this.processedIntegers = processedIntegers;
    }

    private boolean going = true;
    public void stopReadingAndWriting(){
        going = false;
        interrupt();
    }
    public void run(){
        while(going){
            try {
                createdIntegers.put(generateRandomInteger());
                System.out.println(processedIntegers.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException ie){
                // stop-in-the-middle handling code goes here
            }
        }
    }
}

class CalculationThread extends Thread {

    private BlockingQueue<Integer> createdIntegers;
    private BlockingQueue<Integer> processedIntegers;

    public CalculationThread(BlockingQueue<? extends Integer> createdIntegers, BlockingQueue<? extends Integer> processedIntegers){
        this.createdIntegers = createdIntegers;
        this.processedIntegers = processedIntegers;
    }

    private boolean going = true;
    public void stopReadingAndWriting(){
        going = false;
        interrupt();
    }

    public void run(){
        while(going){
            try {
                Integer integer = createdIntegers.take();
                integer = performCalculation(integer);
                processedIntegers.put(integer);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie){
                // stop-in-the-middle handling code goes here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I'd recommend using three threads, one for generating integers, one for calculating, and one for writing. This way the writing or generating speeds aren't tied together.

Note that you can use different implementation of `BlockingQueue` depending on your needs. The [`SynchronousQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) class will give a one-to-one correspondence between putting and taking from the queue, so you won't rack up a large stash of unprocessed or unwritten integers, which can be good for memory but bad if the thread creating the stash hangs for some reason. Other implementations such as [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) allow a buildup of elements sup to a fixed capacity, which improves performance while it's running but also might waste CPU time and memory generating unused elements.

Comment: Well, thanks for help, but I have to use classes PipedOutputStream and PipedInputStream to solve my problem. I can't use anything else.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to learn the principles of java multithreading. I would normally recommend using concurrent queues, but maybe you need to implement something by yourself using synchronization primitives.

The basic things to know are:

- arbitrage between threads for concurrent access
- signaling between threads to indicate a change or the upcoming of certain events

You will need the first to let both threads access the same piece of data without stepping on each others toes, and the second to let each thread know that the other completed its part of the job.

As you indicated it in your question body, the algorithm outline is something like:

- thread (1) set the value
- thread (1) tells thread (2) that it can process the data
- thread (2) updates the value
- thread (2) tells thread (1) that it has finished processing the data
- thread (1) displays the result

If done correctly, you won't actually need to handle concurrent access to the variable, since each thread will do its job separately, and wait the other thread's signal to access the data.

In more details, the overall execution would be like:

- thread (2) waits for thread (1) signal
- thread (1) set the value
- thread (1) tells thread (2) that it can process the data
- thread (1) waits for thread (2) signal
- thread (2) updates the value
- thread (2) tells thread (1) that it has finished processing the data
- thread (1) displays the result

Now you can separate the threads respective instruction sequences to know what each thread needs to do on its own.

[Semaphores](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) are very versatile objects which can be used to signal events between threads, although its interface is not very telling:

- the instance must be initialized to `0`,
- a call to the `acquire` method will be semantically the same as a *wait* for the event
- a call to `release` will correspond to a signal trigger

Each thread hence must hold a reference to the variable to be manipulated, as well as a reference to the same semaphore instance to synchronize on (*).

The next step of your programme will probably be to turn it into a more generic producer consumer setup, where thread one and two work on several values ratlher than just one. This is where you will need to use the concurrent queue classes. That said, given the above explanation, you will probably want to first implement such queue by yourself.

### Edit:

Your update indicates that you wish to use the PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream as the communication medium between your threads.

In this setup, the pipe let your threads synchronize naturally, since the `read` methods of the input pipe are blocking. You will need to provide a pair of input and output pipe to each thread, where the input of the second is `connect`ed to the output of the first, and vice-versa.

The algorithm becomes:

- thread (2) reads from the input pipe (and blocks until it receives it)
- thread (1) computes the initial value
- thread (1) `write`s the value to its output pipe
- thread (1) reads from its input pipe (and blocks)
- thread (2) returns from the call to `read`
- thread (2) process the integer it received
- thread (2) writes back the new value to its ouptput pipe
- thread (1) returns from its `read`
- thread (1) print the result

Like the previous algorithm, each instruction sequence may be separately implemented in its own function. The difficult point will probably to transform the integer back and forth from its native representation to one which may be read and write as a stream of bytes. This process is called serialization and deserialization.

One way consists in using the `Integer` class facilities to convert to and from a `String` (using `toString` and `parseInt` method calls), and then convert the string itself in an array of bytes to use with the streams.

That solution is a bit cumbersome, although it does help in understanding the idea of serialization somewhat. Luckily, Java let you deal with serialization very easily. See this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857105/array-of-int-serialization-java) on that very topic for details and possible pitfall. Since it relies on the same mechanisms as the aformentioned stream methods, the threads will block in a similar manner when trying to deserialize values that haven't been serialized yet.

See the [connect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html#connect(java.io.PipedInputStream)), [read][3] and [write][4] methods of the pipe classes for further details.

---

<sub>(*) I'll spill the (java) beans: you can actually use any java object as a signalling mechanism using the `wait` and `notify` methods on them, but would that be fun for a tutorial?</sub>

[3]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html#read(byte[], int, int)
[4]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html#write(byte[], int, int)

Comment: Well, thanks for help, but I have to use classes PipedOutputStream and PipedInputStream to solve my problem. I can't use anything else.